# 1-dB compression point is in the range of -20 to -25 dBm

Tags: power, rf, gain, units

I am reading the Razavi's textbook `RF Microelectronics 2nd edition` p. 18.

It says

> 1-dB compression point is typically in the range of -20 to -25 dBm (63.2 to 35.6 mVpp in 50-Ohms system) at the input of RF receivers.

I know the definition of dBm is a power level expressed in decibels (dB) with reference to one milliwatt (mW).

However, I still have trouble to calculte -20~-25 dBm and 63.2~35.6.

Could anyone please help me in this? or provide me with some relevant reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to go from dBm to Volts peak-to-peak you have to

1. Convert dBm to it's raw power value over an assumed  \$1 \space\Omega \$ impedance. There's an intermediate step where we must first subtract 30 from the dBm value to yield dB.
2. Multiply the power value by the impedance of the system then take the square root. This value is the real **RMS Voltage**. This is from the classic \$P = \frac{V^2}{Z}\$.
3. Multiply the RMS Voltage by \$\sqrt{2}\$ to yield the absolute *peak* of the Voltage.
4. Multiply by 2 to yield the final peak-to-peak Voltage.

$$V_{RMS} = \sqrt{10^\frac{{dBm - 30}}{10}(50 \space\Omega)}$$

$$V_{peak} = \sqrt{2}V_{RMS}$$

$$V_{pp} = 2V_{peak}$$

For -20 dBm:

$$V_{RMS} = \sqrt{10^\frac{{-20 - 30}}{10}(50 \space\Omega)} = 22.4 \space mV$$

$$V_{peak} = \sqrt{2}(22.4 \space mV) = 31.6 \space mV$$

$$V_{pp} = 2(31.6 \space mV) = 63.2 \space mV$$

Repeating for -25 dBm:

$$V_{RMS} = \sqrt{10^\frac{{-25 - 30}}{10}(50 \space\Omega)} = 12.6 \space mV$$

$$V_{peak} = \sqrt{2}(12.6 \space mV) = 17.8 \space mV$$

$$V_{pp} = 2(17.8 \space mV) = 35.6 \space mV$$

Comment: Nice answer! Would you mind please also hint me how to get -20 to -25 dBm?  What is the rough approach to get these values?   Thanks again!

Comment: @sleevechen It depends on the context. Do you mean in converting from Voltage to dBm? Or how the dBm values were determined in the first place? The latter being determined by the designers of such components.

Comment: Now I see, thanks!